# How do I conditionally change the print.css stylesheet to use media = all

Tags: 7, theming

I added this to my template.php, but it doesn't appear to be working.  I've also placed this code in theme_preprocess_html(),

```
<?php
  function theme_process_html(&$variables) {
    if ($_GET['print'] == 'true'){
      $variables['css']['sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/print.css']['media'] = 'all';
    }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [hook_css_alter(&$css)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7)

```
<?php
  function MYMODULE_css_alter(&$css) {
    if (isset($_GET['print']) && $_GET['print'] == 'true') {
      $css[path_to_theme().'/css/print.css']['media'] = 'all';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Does it work even if css aggregation is turned on?

Comment: Yes, aggregation is called after this hook, so it's aware of the change.

Comment: I thought it would aggregate once, and then leave it as is.